# How to detect when a reactive element updates in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have a standard template that does an {{#each}} with a list of reactive elements from a collection.

The problem I am having is, I want to do a font property change on a particular element whenever it is updated in the collection, just to draw attention to the fact that it was updated.

I haven't been able to find a good / elegant way to do this. Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: So you want an effect similar to what one sees when an answer is added on Stackoverflow?

Comment: yeah, very similar. I am fine writing a jquery animate snippet, it is just opaque to me how I can attach it to an element within a reactive list

Comment: What you can do is use `Session.set('element_id', 'myid')` and check for the Session variable and on change use jquery to animate the element container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to check cursor observe, when some document updates or changed, you can do anything like if event called.

```
li#model-1273927381273 model-1273927381273

Modal.find().observe
    changed: (newDocument, oldDocument) ->
        ($ '#model-'+ newDocument._id).action()

http://docs.meteor.com/#observe

i use similar code currently but dont know how to prevent init documents load.
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your question, I wanted to 'flash' a div whenever a particular session variable (a GPS location) changed. My solution below.

in /client/main.js:

```
Session.setDefault('lat', 0);
Session.setDefault('lng', 0);
Session.setDefault('locationChange', 1);
```

And:

```
Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    getLocation();

}, 5000); 

function getLocation() {
    Location.locate(function(pos){
        var oldLat = Session.get("lat");
        var oldLng = Session.get("lng");

        Session.set('lat', pos.latitude);
        Session.set('lng', pos.longitude);

        if (oldLat != Session.get("lat") || oldLng != Session.get("lng"))
            Session.set("locationChange", -1 * Session.get("locationChange"));

    }, function(err){
        console.log("Location not obtained: ", err);
    });     
}
```

In the template, say /client/templates/someTemplate.html, where I wanted to alert the user to the change:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot" aria-hidden="true" data-locationChange='{{locationChange}}'></span>
```

In the associated javascript file, say /client/templates/someTemplate.js:

```
Template.appBody.helpers({
    locationChange: function() {
        $("#locationIcon").fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);

        return Session.get("locationChange");
    },    
});
```

So, now, whenever the GPS coordinates change (not necessarily when they are refreshed), the value for 'locationChange' is flipped from 1 to -1 or vice versa. This triggers the 'locationChange' helper, which updates the (meaningless) attribute 'data-locationChange', but also triggers some jQuery script that flashes the span in the template.